# How to create dataframe in pyspark with two columns, one string and one array?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a list of strings say

```
id = ['a','b','c']
```

A list of numpy arrays

```
value = [array([1,2]),array([2,3]),array([3,4])]
```

I want to create a pyspark dataframe like

```
| id       | value    |
| -------- | -------- |
| a        | [1,2]    |
| b        | [2,3]    |
| c        | [3,4]    |
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other answer would not work for Numpy arrays. To create a dataframe from numpy arrays, you need to convert it to a Python list of integers first.

```
from numpy import array

id = ['a','b','c']
value = [array([1,2]),array([2,3]),array([3,4])]

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(i, list(map(int, j))) for (i, j) in zip(id, value)],
    ['id', 'value']
)

df.show()
+---+------+
| id| value|
+---+------+
|  a|[1, 2]|
|  b|[2, 3]|
|  c|[3, 4]|
+---+------+

df.printSchema()
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- value: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
id = ['a','b','c']
value = [[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]]
l = list(zip(id, value))
df = spark.createDataFrame(l)
```

[image]